# Overflow error while opening 2nd Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for help after many hours of research.
My problem is a little bit tricky but...
I am working on new Excel-VBA Applications for my company.
I developped some code to help me to open new instances of Excel everytime I open a new workbook.

My problem comes when i try to open a second Excel while my workbook is already open. I get an un-understandable error 6 Overflow.

There are the tools that I developped to open new Excel instances.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents ThisExcelApplication As Application
Private WithEvents OtherExcelApplication As Application
Private l_blnSaveNewWorkbook As Boolean


'Procédure : Workbook_Open
'Event : opening workbook
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Debug.Print Time & " : ThisWorkbook\Workbook_Open()"
    If Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        Call ReOpenApplicationInNewExcelInstance
    Else
        l_blnSaveNewWorkbook = False
    End If

    Set ThisExcelApplication = Application

    Load ufConnection
    ufConnection.Show

End Sub
```

There is my Workbook_open, it checks if there is an existing workbooks opened then it opens my workbook on a new excel instance. But my problem doesn't come from here.

```
Private Sub ThisExcelApplication_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Dim strFile As String

    If Wb.FullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName Then Exit Sub

    Set OtherExcelApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    strFichier = Wb.FullName
    Wb.Close False

    If g_blnApplicationVisibility Then
        ThisExcelApplication.Visible = True
    Else
        ThisExcelApplication.Visible = False
    End If

    OtherExcelApplication.Visible = True
    OtherExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open strFile
End Sub


Private Sub ReOpenApplicationInNewExcelInstance()
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim strFiler As String
    Dim strTemporaryFileName As String

    l_blnSaveNewWorkbook = True

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strTemporaryFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator 
& "TemporaryFileName.xlsb"

    'save current workbook on a temporary file to free the access of original workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strTemporaryFileName 
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'close the original workbook and re-open it on new instance
    oExcel.Workbooks.Open strFile

    'close the 1rst workbook and kill the temporary files
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
    Kill strTemporaryFileName 
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

When I open a second workbook when the 1rst one is already open, the ThisExcelApplication_WorkbookOpen Method is logicaly called. It checks the name of the opened workbooks. If it is not the same name, it tries to open a new excel instance and open this workbook on it.
Then i get the error 6 Overflow on this line :

```
OtherExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open strFichier
```

Maybe someone have an idea to help me?

Thanks a lot for your attention.

PS: Sorry for my english, it might be bad !

Comment: Did you check it row-by-row? Does this error occur on first iteration?

Comment: I suspect it being one of the oddities of Excel 365

Comment: Yeah, this error appears when i open the second workbook. 
The method "ThisExcelApplication_WorkbookOpen" is triggered on my 1rst workbook then at the end of the maccro on the line "OtherExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open strFile" it pops the error. And i work with XL-2013 i don't think it's Excel 365.

Comment: Just another question: If you have Option Explicit in your module why do you still have undeclared variables in the code? What are you doing in the userform ufConnection and where is it declared? Or do you use the "global" instance?

Comment: My module is not complete here, but the problem does not come from the ufConnection because it is already open when i open a second Excel Instance, all my variables are declared. The problem just come from the "ThisExcelApplication_WorbookOpen" method when i try to open the second instance.

Comment: Help again !
My problem is still unsolved.